# display category children from database in certain way to user

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in php/mysql and I just can't get my head wrapped around the following:

I have around 1000 products, each with its own category. The DB structure seems weird but unfortunately this is what I have to work with.

[image]

Because I want the user to walk through the tree I want to set it up as seen on the image below:

[image]

does anyone have a idea on how to do this in the easiest/cleanest way possible?

Comment: Beginner or not, you have to make an attempt first. Post what you tried, and we'll try to help you get it working. We're not here to do your coding for you.

Comment: I will. I'll get back here in a few days.